# Is there a more robust way to integration test my persistance layer app.config?

Tags: mstest, integration-testing, configuration-files

I have my application broken into the following projects/assemblies

- Approot/UI
- AppDomain/business logic/layer

  - Domain.Tests
- Persistance/db layer

  - Persistance.Tests

I'm integration testing the connection string stored in the Persistance assembly using MSTest. currently I am using LocalTestRun.config for the solution to tell it to include the Persistance layer's app.config file for testing, but I imagine this will not work well if any other layers have an app.config file in their test sections. How is this supposed to be set up? `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(assemblyName?)`.

What does adding [DeploymentItem("app.config")] do for the test method?

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("app.config")] // I added this to see if it would help somehow
    public void Configuration_ConnectionStrings_Connect()
    {
    //code omitted
    }
```

Comment: DeploymentItem disconnect the file from the test, making the test harder to understand. It's hard to understand why a test fails if someone delete, rename or move the file. My trick is to embed the file as a resource and let the test setup write it to current directory. That way I have full control of the file location and contents.